# How to visualize GML with C#

Tags: c#, .net, data-visualization, gml, drawingml

I´d like to create program which can visualize geometry from GML format. Please does anybody know if there is some function in .NET or do you know about some free GIS / GeoSpatila toolkit for C# (something like GeoTools for Java)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just google `GeoTools for .net`